# Issue with storing a variable in mousedown - Sencha ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, mousedown

I am having an issue with passing a needed variable in my component class. The problem is when the spinup is clicked, the class is called again and the current_cursor_position is set back to 'undefined'. I have not found of another way to register a mouse down click. It seem am having a real issue between sharing the variable. Any Recommendations?

Thanks in advance,

Code snippet:

```
    current_cursor_position: undefined, //global variable to hold the cursor position that is used when spinUp is click. Also is used to store mouse down position 

init{
        this.getView().addListener('spinup', this.spinnerUp, this);
        this.getView().addListener('spindown', this.spinnerDown, this);

        this.getView().mon(this.getView().getEl(), {
        mousedown: function(e) {

          this.current_cursor_position = //logic to find and store user current mouse click
        }
},

spinnerUp {
this.current_cursor_position = //recorded cursor position 
…
//logic to increment time
}

…
```

Comment: what's your `scope` on `mousedown`?

Comment: It seems the scope is only within init

Answer (score 0):

I was using .mon wrong

this.getView().mon(this.getView().getEl(), 'mousedown', myFunction,this)